# Insert line break into knitr fig.cap?

Tags: r, knitr

I am using `knitr` and want to insert a line break in my `fig.cap` chunk option. Is this possible? The following is all I can think of but it doesn't work. I expect there's some evaluation option but I struggle to understand how evaluation works...

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<chunk1, fig.cap = "This figure is great! Do you \n agree?">>=
plot(1:10)
@


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a LaTeX linebreak instead of an R linebreak and use the caption package. The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[format=plain, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=true]{caption}

\begin{document}

<<chunk1, fig.cap = "This figure is great! Do you \\\\ agree?">>=
plot(1:10)
@

\end{document}
```